# send data array by url does not recognize spaces

Tags: javascript, ajax

I´m selecting data from database as array, it print well in html but sending data by url with javascript does not recognize spaces:

```
 $("." + "content-wrapper").load("almacenes/caja_detalle.php?id_unico="+data[1]+"&nombre_usuario="+data[2]+"&tipo_contenedor="+data[7]+"&nro_contenedor="+data[8]+"");
```

in the code above +data[7]+ contains two words separated by a space (Caja Cartón) but throws the error:

jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Cartón&nro_contenedor=9

I will greatly appreciate help or guidance on how to handle objects with spaces

Comment: Always [encode the values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) before using them in a query string. Also, this question has nothing to do with PHP, MySQL or HTML. Please only add tags that are relevant to the issue/question.

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, there's even an easier way; passing the data as an object to your `load()` function (as an object): `$(...).load('http://example.com', {id_unico: data[1], ...})`. jQuery will then handle all the encoding for you.

Comment: Thank you Eriksson, I no longer get the error, now I just don't know how to collect the values in the page where I had $_GET[], is another method used for this?

Comment: No, it's `$_GET` you use to get values from the query string. Without seeing how you're passing the data, or how you're currently trying to fetch them in PHP, I can't really help you with that.

Comment: Correct answer if someone looking: encodeURIComponent(data[7].trim());
URLs cannot contain spaces. URL encoding normally replaces a space with a plus (+) sign or with %20.

Comment: the `+`, or `%20` is just a urlencoded space (which is 100% valid in a URL). When you recieve the data in PHP, it would just be a space again. If you couldn't get the value at all, then there's something else going on.

Comment: As I said, encodeURIComponent solved. Thanks any way...